# VLC HD 1080p 10bit too slow on my PC

Tags: unity, video, compiz, vlc, amd-graphics

I have not really old pc: 
[image: conf]

However when I play 10bit 1080p on my ubuntu desktop I get lags and I can clearly see that this happens only on fast object/background movements. So it seems that my PC is too dump to decode 10bit.

I enabled video rendering hardware acceleration but as far as I understand VLC can decode only mp4 and mpeg through videocard. Disabling second monitor and setting VLC realtime priority helps a bit.

I remember that 6 years ago when linux was not so stable, I had small eeepc and compiz was really heavy, so I had to choose whether to use compiz or to watch fullscreen video cause I get same kind of lags.

I wonder if I can try to disable window animations on gnome when VLC in fullscreen mode or maybe I can do something else with that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by installing mpv player.

It seems to do hardware acceleration for 10bit fullhd automatically.

Comment: Actually now I am not sure what it does to work better than VLC cause I figured out that I don't have opencl installed. But MPV is definately perfoming better and it even launches faster